# Laravel: Designing a DB table for schedules

Tags: laravel, database-design

I am creating an application and one of it's features is going to be a person scheduler - you know, to create work schedules for staff members for the current & next months, where to write shifts, sick-leaves, day-offs, etc.

Right now I designed a structure using JSON format, like so:

[image]

Here, the `schedule` field contains a schedule for a corresponding month for the corresponding staff member in JSON format, like this: `[{"date": "2020-10-01", "shift": "B"},{"date": "2020-10-02","shift": "B"}, ...]`.

This structure works and chose it because it won't overload the DB with tons of entries for each day multiplied by the staff member quantity. But I realized that I won't be able to search some fields, I will also need to calculate the Total working hours (and other hours) in my PHP AND JS as well, that means a lot of work and load for the server.

The second version is to make a table with just `id (int), staff_id (int), date (date), value (string)`, where the shift (value) will be stored for each staff member for each day. But I may assume that it is going to be quite heavy after, let's say, a year of usage with 10 staff members (at lease 3650 entries). But this will make it easier to search data, make statistic reports, make hour calculations (using only JS) and will simplify the server-side code.

The `staff_id` will contain an ID of the staff member and I will access that data using Eloquent relationship.

For you, as an expert, what version is better and why (speaking about application performance)? Won't the DB entry quantity drastically affect it?

P.S. Let's ignore the exporting features for now, but I understand that I will only be able to export this table, while only using version 2 of this.

P.P.S. I am using MySQL (for dev environment) and MariaDB (for staging and production).

Thank you!

Comment: 1) 3650 records per year is peanuts for even the most basic server. 2) if you are using a relational database, then use it as a relational database and don't store data structures in a field as value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Avoid storing structured data in RDBMS in JSON

MySQL and such are RDBMSes (Relational Database Management Systems). If you can define a table structure in terms of columns, you should always **avoid storing data in JSON** when using RDBMS. Reason being JSON-related database queries are likely slower (requires parsing JSON and because JSON columns can store unstructured data).

It also won't be surprising that storing data with a JSON equivalent format will take more space as well, because you repeat the key `"date"` and `"shift"` every row. This will also take a toll on networking load which I'll talk about later. How MySQL stores data is "comparable" to a CSV. You can try at this site [CSVJSON](https://csvjson.com/) I just found on Google search, and observe how much more space JSON consumes.

Also, You will likely be **less flexible with queries** and **won't be able to take advantage with some of the Laravel features (really important)**.

I advice storing the schedules in another table, forming a one-to-many (schedules to shifts) relationship.

Then you'll be able to do something like this, assuming the table in your screenshot is called `schedules` and the `schedule` column is transformed into a table called `shifts`.

```php
class Schedule extends Model {
  function shifts() {
    return $this->hasMany(Shift::class);
  }
}
```

```php
$staffSchedule = Schedule::whereStaffId(1)->first();
$numOfShifts = $staffSchedule->shifts()->count(); // You can query build off of `shifts()`
$shifts = $staffSchedule->shifts; // Magic property that returns a collection of shifts
```

#### Calculate everything using SQL if possible, then server-side web framework. Client-side calculation is last resort.

Reasons being:

- Servers are assumed to be more powerful machines.
- Returning intermediate results require **much** network traffic.

  Your application will be slow if your clients have to download MBs of data with slow Internet. Optimize at transferring as little data over network as possible over attempting to offload computation to the client side.
- Hydrating Laravel Models from DB results use up **more** unnecessary computing resources.

  You can sometimes even reach PHP memory limit if you are dealing with lots of rows coupled with bad code
- Computation in PHP is likely to be slower than in SQL.

  Often you might want to go through a couple of relationships, this DB access overhead really slows down computation. e.g. You received n models and want to count each of their shifts.

  ```php
  // Just a toy example. No one would realistically do this.
  $schedules = Schedules::where(/*...*/)->get(); // 1 SQL call returns n objects
  $totalShiftCount = $schedules->map(
     fn (Schedule $schedule) => $schedule->shifts()->count()
  )->sum(); // n SQL calls. BAD! Avoid scaling SQL calls to number of rows.
  ```

Laravel would one by one wait for the SQL result for that row and construct a model representing the row's data before running the next SQL. **It's this overhead that slows down execution**.

Avoid using Laravel models if you want to calculate something, but would require accessing thousands of rows and won't use the models otherwise. If you can't form your query using Laravel query builder, form one using [raw expressions](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#raw-expressions). Strive to **write 1 SQL query** that does everything you need.

Trust me, calculating something using Laravel models instead of pure SQL is **multitudes slower**. Passing unnecessary data to the client side will often take a bigger toll on your server because you are sending out unicode encoded JSON data instead of doing the calculations yourself on the server.

---

Not sure if I've answered to all your concerns, but feel free to comment down below if you have anything you wish me to clarify.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! It is the explanation I was looking for. So, basically, you offer to use SQL calculated fields to calculate total hours an employee worked for the current month? Is that correct? Why shouldn't I do it in my Controller class that is basically a bridge between the Model and an HTTP Request? Didn't understand the part with calculations inside the Model

Comment: @MaxKrizh Perhaps I was using too much jargon. Basically, if you want to calculate in PHP, normally you might want to execute a number of queries (perhaps proportional to the num of rows). Establishing a connection to the database and waiting for an answer one by one running in a serial manner immensely slows down the execution time. Take my toy example, Laravel would one by one wait for the SQL result for that row and construct a model representing the row's data before running the next SQL. It's this overhead that slows down execution.

Comment: @MaxKrizh The approach of storing everything within JSONs are also prevalent nowadays, but that's not really the preferred way to be using with Laravel. You can read on "NoSQL databases" like MongoDB and Elasticsearch if you want to learn more on how this works. They are popular databases which store entire nested data structures within 1 document instead of across many tables.

Comment: yeah, I know about Elasticsearch, since I work with Magento 2 and I know that a JSON format is okay there. Since I developed the structure for the current app, I was in doubt if the JSON is the most suitable for current framework and DBMS. Also, the quantity of entries (number of days x number of employee) made me a bit confused about what it is going to be more productive

Comment: @MaxKrizh Ah, now I understand. I just assumed you approached database management with RDBMS since that was the norm. In fact, I just started working with Elasticsearch and hit my head **a lot** coming from RDBMS. Yeah, basically don't bring along the paradigm with the other database format and learn everything anew, haha. That's really for reminding myself. Good luck to you!